# AUC for basic models is higher than bagged models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, svm, cross-validation

Is correct to get a bit lower AUC with bagged algorithms than no bagged algorithms? The first figure shows the ROC with bagged algorithms and the second figure shows the ROC without bagging. The curves represents the mean function in a 10-fold cross validation.

[image: ROC bagged algorithms]

[image: ROC algorithms]

As expected the mean accuracy of a 10-fold cross validation with bagged algorithms (1st Figure below) is higher than without bagging (2nd Figure below):

[image]

[image]

I thought that bagging algorithms performs better than without bagging. Am I wrong?